# How to get the revision number for particular property value

Tags: svn

I need to get revision number for a specific custom property. for example i have set custom property 'Label' with value 'Test' at revision no 130.

Now i need to get the revision no (130) with the help of Property name('Label') and value('Test') by using svn command line client(svn.exe,svnmucc.exe,svnlook.exe,...).

How can i get ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want someone to answer your question first accept an answer of your other questions.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer - **no way**

Longer answer - Subversion have good natural way from revision to property (and value), but not in inverse way, at least without a lot of handwork. SVN Book [specially note it](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.props.html)

> For all their utility, Subversion properties — or, more accurately, the available interfaces to them — have a major shortcoming: while it is a simple matter to set a custom property, finding that property later is a whole different ball of wax.
>
> Trying to locate a custom revision property generally involves performing a linear walk across all the revisions of the repository, asking of each revision, “Do you have the property I'm looking for?” Use the --with-all-revprops option with the svn log command's XML output mode to facilitate this search.
>
> ...
>
> Trying to find a custom versioned property is painful, too, and often involves a recursive svn propget across an entire working copy.